# How frequently are PG tables refreshed in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I amusing the below code to check for empty tables in redshift:

```
SELECT n.nspname, c.relname
FROM pg_class c
INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON (n.oid = c.relnamespace)
WHERE c.reltuples = 0 AND c.relkind = 'r' and nspname = 'public'
```

Obviously this is based on pg_class being updated. I recently dropped a table, but it still returns in this query. When can I expect it to vanish? Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANALYZE.html